# The purpose of x and y in KineticJs Line

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am working on an application that make use of kineticJs. I am looking into learning about Kinetic.Line . In the line constructor, there is the member variable x and y as well as points(which is an array of points). What does the position x and y represents since there is the points array? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{x,y}` is common position of `Kinetic.Node` element.
IF you need to change whole position of `Kinetic.Line` it is much easier to change just x and y then all points in array.

Also `x,y` properties are changed while dragging, not `points`.